# In Go, Given an interface{} in which I know what interface it implements, how can I convert to it

Tags: go, interface

My current problem is that I am implementing data-structures and I have written iterators for them.  I have visible interfaces for my data-structures, iterators, and all other required objects.  In the back I have concrete implementations which I wish to hide from the end user.

This requires many of my functions to return interface{} objects so that I can store any type of object (and leave validation up to the end-user).

One problem I have is that I iterate over a Graph.  My iterator{} for my graph implementation returns a concrete vertex type but the Iterator interface returns interface{}.  Since the end-users can only my base Vertex interface I have to try to convert to a Vertex interface so they can use it.

Here is the smallest example that I could think of at this point which illustrates my issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Base interface {
    Required() string
}

type Concrete struct {
    _data int
}
func (con *Concrete) Required() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(con._data)
}

func convert(val interface{}) *Base {
    if con,ok := val.(*Base); ok {
        return con
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    conc := new(Concrete)
    conc._data = 5

    base := convert(conc)

    fmt.Println(base)
}
```

In the code above I really wish that convert would convert the type to *Base.  The function convert will return the value nil instead of the lovely value I wish it to be.

---

Edit: Removed unused code, I thought I had already removed it but I guess not.

Comment: If you look at the [specification of type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) you'll see your `convert` function is just `base, _ := conc.(Base)`. It will return the zero value (nil for a pointer) as appropriate. However, ignoring the boolean is rarely desired. If your code expects that it's the only thing adding elements then using `base := conc.(Base)` is appropriate. You want the runtime to panic when it detects a mistake in your code just as a failed slice/array bounds check will panic.

Comment: @DaveC The reason I have a method is because I call it in a few places.  If I change the underlying type I don't want to have to change it in a bunch of places.  The only reason I left the boolean check was because I liked how it looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have finished writing this long explanation I had an idea and  figured out the solution:

```
func convert(val interface{}) Base {
    if con,ok := val.(Base); ok {
        return con
    }
    return nil
}
```

Don't try to cast to a pointer but rather just the Base interface.

I am not sure why this is the case.  When I do reflect.TypeOf(val) inside of convert it gives the output

```
*main.Concrete
```

I hope that other people find this useful and that someone else can answer the **why** portion of this answer.

Comment: You almost never want to use a pointer to an interface. E.g. `*bytes.Buffer` (a pointer to a struct type) is common but `*io.Reader` is almost always a mistake. To really understand why might require reading something like: [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

Comment: @DaveC Thanks for the link will check it out.  The one thing that throws me is that if I want to convert a pointer to some struct to an interface then I don't keep it as a pointer.  The one question I have is what happens to the pointer part.  How can I convert from a pointer to a non-pointer type/interface?

Comment: It's all explained at that link. The interface value will point to whatever the underlying type is and if that's `*Concrete` so be it. A pointer to an interface doesn't implement that interface (e.g. `func f(r io.Reader, rp *io.Reader)` can call `r.Read` but cannot call `rp.Read`).